# Eclipse Kepler does not allow debugging on Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: android, eclipse, samsung-mobile, android-4.3-jelly-bean, android-debug

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S4 I9505 (Jelly Bean 4.3) as my debug target, and I've done the preliminary steps already:

1. Tapped 7 times on the "Build Number" under "My Device" to enable developer menu
2. Enabled USB Debugging from the device
3. Unchecked the "Verify apps via USB" to make sure my app is not blocked
4. Downloaded the OEM driver for Samsung from [Samsung Andorid USB Driver for Windows](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows)
5. Installed the driver successfully.

When I connect my device via USB, Eclipse sees my device but does not allow me to debug on it.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing Android on Windows, then Windows may have allow you to "see" your device. But to connect to your Samsung Galaxy S4 I9505, you may need to install the **Samsung USB drivers for mobile devices v1.5.33.0**, which can be found [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=11633550#post11633550).

After installation, you may need to restart your computer. Once the computer has restarted, start a command prompt and navigate to **\android-sdk\platform-tools**. Then, type each command below in succession:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices
```

The last command will tell you whether you are truly connected to your device and the device is ready for debugging in Eclipse.

Comment: **Already done and still no help.** My device is displayed in the adb prompt.

Comment: Make sure your Android SDK and ADT have exact versions. Varying versions can cause unforseen problems. Also, I'm assuming from your post that you're using Windows - but which version? And are you using JDK v6 (1.6.45) or v7. Note: JDK v7 is currently not supported by Android. You'll need to install JDK v6 and then point to the installed JDK location in Eclipse. –

Comment: I have JDK 7, I will install JDK 6 and try again, @CKD Publishing